# How to use Gitlab CI variables in ArgoCD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, argocd

I have a project that was being deployed on Kubernetes using Helm on a Gitlab pipeline so far,

In the helm values file, there is a `deployment.containers[0].serviceNameTag` and it's set to `main` by default, but sometimes, I change it using `--set` in my pipeline when deploying and set it to `${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}` which is available on GitLab.

Now I'm using ArgoCD instead, but I don't know how to access that `${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}` available on my Gitlab pipeline, how can I access that value and similar values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: GitOps requires you to change how you approach problems. ArgoCD is not a 1:1 replacement of a traditional CD pipeline, and the root cause of your problem is that your deployment strategy is not designed for GitOps. You need to rethink the way you deploy your projects.

This said, one way to achieve this would be to set up an additional step in the pipeline that packages the software to be deployed. That way you know to which software commit, your deployment references.

Example using yq:

```bash
yq -i 'deployment.containers[0].serviceNameTag = strenv(CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG)' values.yaml
```